# Rails 4.2 with Kaminari 0.17.0 - how to change "?page=x" to "/x" (ie no query string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paging, kaminari, custom-url

Whilst I understand that Tim Berners Lee [specified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) the use of ? for dynamic url segments, the client on my project doesn't want them.

So does anyone know how, using Kaminari for paging, I can change the routing to replace:

```
domain.com/searchresults?page=x
```

with

```
domain.com/searchresults/x
```

Obviously, this has to work when you click next page, prev page etc so that the url always changes x to the correct page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs I missed that you can add a concern in the routes, like this:

```
concern :paginatable do
  get '(page/:page)', :action => :index, :on => :collection, :as => ''
end
```

Then apply the concern:

```
resources :my_resources, :concerns => :paginatable
```